# Huge packet loss on openwrt

Tags: networking, openwrt, tcpdump

I have a strange issue on mikrotik rb951-2hnd router. I built image a few years ago using [revision 39392 and patch](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/mikrotik/rb951g_2hnd#compile_openwrt_yourself) firmwared it and everything worked fine. Just a few months ago I decided to update firmware. So I did it and discovered that **physical network is completely broken**. I have **over 90% packet loss** via ethernet ports, though **wifi works perfect** . I thought that I messed up while build. So I firmwared 2 different images from download.openwrt and a couple  more that I built by myself, but symptoms are always the same. I wanted to try worked for me svn revision but unfortunately this patch is unavailable so I can't firmare image back. The funny thing that **everything including physical ports works while netbooting via vmlinux-initramfs (bootp)** the same build revision.  Since vmlinux works fine I suspect that flash is damaged so I made myself sure that files from rootfs.tar.gz and firmwared ones are the same.  On the next step I compared the loaded demons on vmlinux-initramfs and firmwared system, the firmwared one has extra listed below:

```
nf_log_common.ko
nf_log_ipv4.ko
nf_log_ipv6.ko
nf_nat_masquerade_ipv4.ko
nf_reject_ipv4
nf_reject_ipv4.ko
nf_reject_ipv6
nf_reject_ipv6.ko
nls_base.ko
```

Preventing them from loading doesn't help. Furthermore I get **no  errors from dmesg or logread**. Here's my configuration:
[top](http://textuploader.com/8dfa)
[iptables -L -n](http://textuploader.com/70gg)
[/etc/config/network](http://textuploader.com/70uq) - 1 wan. 2-5 lan (wifi in sta client mode)

### scenario for dhcp:

After plugging laptop (dhcp client) to lan port for 15 seconds ( plug out after) I see the followings:

- Laptop send:  3 dhcp request and 9 icmpv6
- Laptop receive: 0  packets
- router sends: None ? (ifconfig displays 4 packets but tcpdump doesn't catch them)
- router receives: 2 icmp packets from
  Laptop sent list (listed below)

I also checked tcpdump on router, and it doesn't show lost packets. Seems like the problem is somewhere on the driver level. But wait, vmlinux works and drivers (kernel modules) are the same.

```
root@OpenWrt:/# tcpdump -vv -i eth0.3
tcpdump: WARNING: eth0.3: no IPv4 address assigned
tcpdump: listening on eth0.3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
[ 1042.060000] Atheros AR8216/AR8236/AR8316 ag71xx-mdio.0:00: Port 2 is up
09:35:24.172637 IP6 (hlim 1, next-header Options (0) payload length: 36) :: > ff02::16: HBH (rtalert: 0x0000) (padn) [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, m]
09:35:25.872843 IP6 (hlim 255, next-header ICMPv6 (58) payload length: 16) fe80::b2e3:928a:66b2:ff43 > ff02::2: [icmp6 sum ok] ICMP6, router6
          source link-address option (1), length 8 (1): 5c:f9:dd:48:9e:89
            0x0000:  5cf9 dd48 9e89
5c:f9:dd:48:9e:89 /fe80::b2e3:928a:66b2:ff43 - laptop,  d4:ca:6d:92:a4:7e / fe80::d6ca:6dff:fe92:a47e: - router
```

### scenario for static ip:

```
openwrt (static 192.168.2.1)
root@OpenWrt:/# ping 192.168.2.2
PING 192.168.2.2 (192.168.2.2): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.505 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: seq=21 ttl=64 time=0.489 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: seq=34 ttl=64 time=0.528 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: seq=39 ttl=64 time=0.512 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: seq=45 ttl=64 time=0.527 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: seq=48 ttl=64 time=0.549 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.2.2: seq=51 ttl=64 time=0.813 ms
^C
--- 192.168.2.2 ping statistics ---
56 packets transmitted, 7 packets received, 87% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.489/0.560/0.813 ms
laptop (static 192.168.2.2)
14:50:08:andrew:/home/andrew:0
: ping 192.168.2.1
PING 192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.2.2 icmp_seq=13 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.2 icmp_seq=14 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.2.2 icmp_seq=15 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 192.168.2.1 ping statistics ---
100 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 99022ms
pipe 3
14:51:53:andrew:/home/andrew:1
: ping 192.168.2.1
PING 192.168.2.1 (192.168.2.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.2.1 ping statistics ---
29 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 28080ms
```

### So here is my question:

What steps should I take to dive deeper and find out what the problem is? I want to find at least the error. Should I turn a debug level somewhere? What can cause such a huge packet loss?

**EDIT**
 Netbooting vmlinux produces the same
 Netbooting [kerneldebug](http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/ar71xx/mikrotik/kernel-debug.tar.bz2) - works perfectly, unfortunately its size is 11mb, mtd1 is to small to hold it.

Comment: Which version of OpenWRT were you using before and which one are you using now? I have the exact same router and using the stable Barrier Breaker (14.07) release I've never had a single networking issue. Haven't tried the Chaos Calmer (15.05) RC images yet - are these the ones you're playing with? As you wrote you are comfortable with building OpenWRT images yourself, try building a kernel with `CONFIG_AG71XX_DEBUG` set to enable debug messages. Note you might have to play with the `ag71xx_msg_level` parameter as well to get any output. Also, does `top` or `free` show anything suspicious?

Comment: I checked `barrier breaker` and `chaos calmer` from downloads.openwrt. I  think i had been running some `attitude_adjustment` revision built by myself when everything worked. Free says that only 17M ram is used. Also I added `top` but cpu loaded only for <3%. I need to add `CONFIG_AG71XX_DEBUG` to `.config`  and `ag71xx_msg_level` belongs to  `/package/boot/uboot-ar71xx/files/cpu/mips/ar71xx_serial.c` ?

Comment: Well, the sole fact that Barrier Breaker gives you issues while it's rock stable on an identical piece of hardware elsewhere is odd. I understand there is no chance you can revert to the previously used OpenWRT version? I'm wondering whether you'd be getting the same behavior after a downgrade. As for `ag71xx_msg_level`, I meant the one in `target/linux/ar71xx/files/drivers/net/ag71xx/ag71xx_main.c`.

Comment: Ah, I forgot to mention. When I updated openwrt (after 1st firmwared worked image) I move back to RouterOs ( to set boot option to LAN 1st  to boot from `initramfs`) and then I firmwared openwrt. I'm not exactly sure but this could update the boot partition and cause the issue. I'm compiling the image with debug=16 for now, see what it changes.

Comment: Well, I'm definitely not a Mikrotik expert, so I can't tell you whether it could break something, but what I know for sure is that I never did a single thing in RouterOS, using the alternative method described in the [OpenWRT wiki](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/mikrotik/rb951ui) to force a one-time netboot.

Comment: I've compiled the last svn revision today applying [Kempniu](http://unix.stackexchange.com/users/74711/kempniu) suggestions. But it seems there're no new entries in [logread](http://textuploader.com/8h18) and [dmesg](http://textuploader.com/8hra)

Comment: That's weird, but to be honest I never enabled these debug messages myself, so I'm afraid I can't help with them. Yet, it's good that you pasted your dmesg as I noticed some differences comparing it with [mine](http://pastebin.com/NUCkR0ju), at least when you grep for `ag71`. Note that these messages were dumped from Barrier Breaker 14.07, r42625. It looks like a different PHY driver is used for the built-in switch in your case, so it looks relevant, but on the other hand, you said Barrier Breaker gives you issues as well, so it's hard to be sure. Any chance you can flash BB to compare dmesg?

Comment: I remembered that I used http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/mikrotik/rb951g_2hnd#compile_openwrt_yourself revision and patch, but unfortunately patch is unavaliable now so I can't rebuilt the image. I also tries a new semptember 2015 chaos calmer 15-05 image - results are the same.

Comment: I'm sure that's not what you would like to hear, but I just upgraded OpenWRT to Chaos Calmer on my RB951Ui-2HnD and everything is peachy.

Comment: Ok this could mean only 3 things: 1) I'm flashing it wrong way 2) It's some kind of hardware issue (but damn, it still works with 11mb debug kernel) 3) Your bootloader differs from mine. After loading initramfs via bootp I `dd; chmod+x` vmlinux-lzma.elf  to mtdblock1 and untar DefaultNoWifi-rootfs.tar.gz to mtdblock2. The images I get from [openwrt](http://downloads.openwrt.org/chaos_calmer/15.05/ar71xx/mikrotik/). I don't do any configuration after flashing, everything should work fine out of the box. There must be a difference I'm just feeling I'm doing something wrong!

Comment: How exactly are you using `dd`? [This](http://pastebin.com/rXyfFka3) is what I'm doing after booting from initramfs and [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1SzqtulkLwGMFlncTg3OEUyWk0) is the gzipped image of my bootloader partition, in case you're feeling adventurous. Running `dd if=/dev/mtdblock0 | md5sum` while in initramfs yields *a145b581f51e391a7d8c193480c6bf93*.

Comment: I did the same as you did, I've meant `cp`. Ok i finally found the reason. Initramfs wasn't the key of working network. It turns out that ethernet ports only work if router was booted with pressed reset button. This is really bizarre...

Comment: ...and sounds like some hardware quirk after all. You should be able write an answer to your own question so that anyone facing a similar issue won't have to read through the whole discussion to get to the "solution".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally found the reason. Initramfs wasn't the key of success. It turns out that routerboard works if it was booted with pressed reset button. But it seems like flashed driver can't last for long. Router reboots with kernel panic after a few hours of using depending on loading rate.